# Need more clue to find i386-pc/normal.mod

Tags: dual-boot, grub, boot-loader

I am on grub rescue mode, and the avalible command just ls, the search, search.file not there.

I already found my partition which use ext2, that is hd0 msdos6.

When i do ls, it consist of
tmp/ root/ var/ dev/ proc/ run/ sys/

What we are looking to normal boot is root also boot right?

But where is the boot/ ?
I don't even know why the grub is broken right now.

I am already aware that it can be fixed by another linux like boot seq dick , but i am hesitant to do that. Because i need to borrow someone pc to install it on a thumb drive first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to rely on iso-tools like boot repair disk.

And i recommend use rufus over unetbootin in this case.

Just to prevent additional annoyance.

Specific if you had dual boot, the tools might restore the windows ( if any) over linux.

To prevent that you can click the advanced optios then mbr options tab.
Then select the proper partition you want.
Selection wrong partition also cause a boot failure. So please becareful.

You can utilize the ship-in gparted to help you find correct partition

Answer (score 1):

> When i do ls, it consist of tmp/ root/ var/ dev/ proc/ run/ sys/

This indeed looks like a root filesystem, but:

- `/bin` should be a directory on the root filesystem (or a symlink to `/usr/bin` in some new distributions) but it's missing
- there should be `/boot` either as a mount point for the `/boot` filesystem or just as a regular directory, but it's missing
- `/dev` is a mount point for the RAM-based `/dev` filesystem, it's there
- `/etc` should always be a directory on the root filesystem, it's missing
- if there is not a separate `/home` partition, then `/home` should also be a regular directory; also missing
- `/lib` should be similar to `/bin`, also missing
- `/media` and `/mnt` should be basically empty directories to be used as mount points for removable media and sysadmin operations, these are missing
- `/proc` is a mount point for `/proc` virtual filesystem, it's there
- `/root` is there
- `/run` is a mount point for a RAM-based tmpfs dedicated for PID files and other run-time state, it's there
- `/sbin` should be similar to `/bin`, it's missing
- `/sys` is a mount point for the `sysfs` virtual filesystem, it's there
- `/tmp` is often a mount point for a RAM-based `tmpfs`
- `/usr` should in modern systems be a regular directory on the root filesystem, but it's missing
- `/var` might be a regular directory or a mount point, it's there

Uh Oh... this looks like a result of `sudo rm -rf /` or similar. If that's true, then a missing `i386-pc/normal.mod` is going to be **the least of your worries**.

Most of the things that are still there on your root partition are directories that are used as mount points for other filesystems when the system is normally running. The few remaining normal directories are all towards the end of the alphabetic sorting order.

Active mount points cannot be removed by `rm -rf` without unmounting them first, which might explain most of the directories that are still there.

The others (basically just `/root` and `/var`) might have been saved just by pure luck: the system may have crashed as essential system libraries in `/lib` and `/usr/lib` (and/or the `rm` command itself) were deleted, before the deletion of `/root` and `/var` had time to complete.

I'm sorry to say that this looks like a system that is somewhere between "severely damaged" and "completely destroyed", assuming that you've identified the partition correctly.

You might want to boot from a live Linux media and mount all the partitions (read-only at first!) to see if any important files have been spared from destruction. and recover everything you can **to a different disk.** If you want to try and recover deleted files, **do not write anything to this partition** and **do not run `fsck`** until you've exhausted all recovery possibilities (including, but not limited to scanning the partition contents with [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)) and are ready to give up hope of rescuing any further data.

Comment: May I ask your aid [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/648824/stuck-at-busy-box-attempt-to-boot-old-linux-at-another-partition)?